# Odoo how to trigger kit purchase order from manufacturing order

Tags: triggers, odoo, odoo-13, purchase-order

I've a Manufactured Product with a BOM of 3 kits (K1, K2, K3).
Once i try to manufacture it, and its components aren't available, i want to trigger a purchase

order containing 3 lines:

1. Line 1 = K1
2. Line 2 = K2
3. Line 3 = K3

What happens is that Odoo create a purchase order containing 1 line for each component of the kits (K1, K2, K3).

I want to extend the manufacturing module to implement my need, how can i do ? which module should i extend ? any guide could be helpful !

Comment: What is the problem? By what you describe, it sounds like Odoo does what you want. Can you explain what it does now compared to what you want it to do?

Comment: Odoo create a purchase order witht he components of K1, K2, K3 as purchase lines not K1, K2, K3. If for example K1 was made with KI11 and KI12 , then in the purchase order you'll have 2 lines KI11 and KI12 not K1

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, then you want to create a Manufacturing Order for **Manufactured Product** which generates a Purchase Order for *the products that make up the components* (instead of a Purchase Order for the components themselves).

---

You would need to have an overall Product/BOM Structure like this:

```
Manufactured Product
├── Kit 1
│   ├── Purchased Product 11
│   └── Purchased Product 12
├── Kit 2
│   └── Purchased Product 13
└── Kit 3
    ├── Purchased Product 14
    ├── Purchased Product 15
    └── Purchased Product 16
```

It sounds like your **Kit #** products are set up with **Routes** as *Make To Order + Buy*. This causes those products to be purchased.

Instead, your **Kit #** products should be set up with **Routes** as *Make To Order + Manufacture* with their own BOM of **BoM Type** Kit.

The Purchased Products should be assigned as BOM Lines on the relevant BOM and those purchased products should be set up with **Routes** as *Make To Order + Buy*.

---

Here is a simplified example of the 2-level BOM setup I'm talking about.

#### BOM for *Manufactured Product*

```
Manufactured Product
├── Kit 1
├── Kit 2
└── Kit 3
```

#### BOM for *Kit 1*

```
Kit 1
├── Purchased Product 11
└── Purchased Product 12
```

Comment: The structure is wrong, it's more like 

Manufactured Product
    -> Purchased Kit # 1 -> (
        Unpurchased Product 11 +
        Unpurchased Product 22 
)

Comment: Can your MO BOM use those purchased products as the BOM Lines? If not, I think you have to have another BOM to kit the purchased products.